# ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected Query

Tags: java, sql, oracle

Given query executes fine when running on ORACLE SQL Developer. but  throws `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected` when executing through java code.

```
UPDATE RESTRICTED_MARKET_OWNER
SET OWNER_ID='abc'
WHERE OWNER_ID='xyz' AND RESTRICTED_MARKET_ID IN
(
    SELECT M.RESTRICTED_MARKET_ID
    FROM RESTRICTED_MARKET M, RESTRICTED_MARKET_OWNER RM
    WHERE RM.RESTRICTED_MARKET_ID = M.RESTRICTED_MARKET_ID AND
          M.RELEASE='Rel123' AND RM.OWNER_ID='xyz'
)
```

any suggestion on this

Java query

```
    UPDATE RESTRICTED_MARKET_OWNER SET OWNER_ID=? WHERE OWNER_ID=? AND RESTRICTED_MARKET_ID IN ( SELECT M.RESTRICTED_MARKET_IDFROM RESTRICTED_MARKET  M  , RESTRICTED_MARKET_OWNER RM WHERE RM.RESTRICTED_MARKET_ID=M.RESTRICTED_MARKET_ID AND M.RELEASE=? AND RM.OWNER_ID=? )

pstmt.setString(1, 'abc');
pstmt.setString(2, 'xyz');
pstmt.setString(3, 'Rel123');
pstmt.setString(4, 'xyz');
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Can you output the query which Java claims it is executing?

Comment: Show us the Java code.

Comment: Modified post  added java query with parameters

Comment: `SELECT M.RESTRICTED_MARKET_IDFROM RESTRICTED_MARKET  M`, is it a typo before the FROM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a typo in your Java query, there's a missing space between the table name and the `FROM` keyword:

```
SELECT M.RESTRICTED_MARKET_IDFROM RESTRICTED_MARKET M.
```

So correcting the syntax would get your query to work fine.